# Why are the modifier sizes not overwritten?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a composable function it assigns a size to a surface.

```kotlin
@Composable
private fun CreateImage(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    Surface(
        modifier = modifier
            .size(150.dp)
            .padding(5.dp),
        shape = CircleShape,
        border = BorderStroke(1.dp, Color.LightGray)
    ) {
        Image(
            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.profile_image),
            contentDescription = "Profile Image",
            contentScale = ContentScale.Crop
        )
    }
}
```

When I call another method and change the size in the modifier parameter shouldn't it stick to 150dp.

If I call this method:

```kotlin
@Composable
private fun ChangeSize(name: String) {
    CreateImage(Modifier.size(100.dp))
}
```

It stays with the size 100dp even though in CreateImage I set it to 150dp. Why is the size not changing to 150dp and staying 100dp?

I thought it was supposed to change it to 150dp. Why is that not the case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Modifier uses first size it got and it's a great feature when people don't provide any size to your Composable.

For instance

```
  CircleDisplay(
        modifier = circleModifier
            .widthIn(min = 70.dp)
            .heightIn(min = 70.dp),
        color = color
    )
```

if anyone doesn't provide any Modifier with any width or height instead of having 0 height and width you give a minimum size to your Composable. You can change this to max or exact size depending on your implementation. But when user modifier has some width height instead of yours the one provided by them is used thanks to using first size.

Default Composables like Slider also use this pattern, so without setting any dimension it has 48.dp height and fills max width of its parent.

BoxWithConstraint under Slider is as

```
    BoxWithConstraints(
        modifier
            .minimumTouchTargetSize()
            .requiredSizeIn(minWidth = ThumbRadius * 2, minHeight = ThumbRadius * 2)
            .sliderSemantics(value, tickFractions, enabled, onValueChange, valueRange, steps)
            .focusable(enabled, interactionSource)
    ) {
     // Rest of the Slider Implementation

}
```

Comment: It worked, thanks. Is it also the same for other modifier properties?

Comment: If you chain Modifier.padding(10.dp).padding(30.dp).padding(100.dp) you will see that it will have only 10.dp padding. But if you set dimension or background or border between then each padding will be applied individually like width and height does. I think it only applies to Modifiers that use `LayoutModifier`. You can draw multiple borders or background chained one after another. Also another detail in Slider source code it's not only for providing default size also setting minimum size so if user gives a smaller dimension that 48.dp which is minimum touch size, it jumps to start.

Comment: My example was only for this purpose. Slider code is just an example they use the same pattern as mentioned above but  it's not only for setting dimensions when developer doesn't provide any size also to force developer to not use size lower than 48 dp  unless  `CompositionLocalProvider(LocalMinimumTouchTargetEnforcement provides false)` is called or the one smaller than in requiredSize. Distinction is Modifier.requiredX unlike `Modifier.size()` or `Modifier.sizeIn()` checks dimensions before it,  if they are not in this constraints of Modifier.requiredX() then Composable jumps to start

Comment: @Thracian If I'm not mistaken, chaining padding modifiers will add them up. Chaining `Modifier.padding(10.dp).padding(30.dp).padding(100.dp)` will result in 140dp padding

Answer (score -1):

The reason why your composable will always have a size of 150.dp is because of how modifiers are applied. When modifiers are chained onto a composable, they are applied sequentially from top to bottom until the last modifier is applied. This can be demonstrated with a very simple `Box` composable

```
@Composable 
fun Screen(){
  Box(
      modifier = Modifier
                  .size(100.dp)
                  .background(color = Color.Yellow)
                  .background(color = Color.Green)
                  .background(color = Color.Red)
  )
```

In this simple `Box` composable, the rendered color will be `Color.Red` because it will be the last color applied before it gets drawn onto the screen.

A similar thing is happening in your example above. Even though you are calling your composable with a modifier of 100.dp, the final size that get's applied is 150.dp because your modifier with 100.dp get's applied too early in the modifier chain.

Replace your composable with this one and it should work as expected

```
@Composable
private fun CreateImage(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    Surface(
        modifier = Modifier
            .size(150.dp)
            .padding(5.dp)
            .then(modifier), //this last modifier will override everything above
        shape = CircleShape,
        border = BorderStroke(1.dp, Color.LightGray)
    ) {
        Image(
            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.profile_image),
            contentDescription = "Profile Image",
            contentScale = ContentScale.Crop
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually the opposite is happening; 100dp is the size that is being applied when I use the method not 150dp. That is what I did not understand. Even I thought that it would work how you told it would but it worked the opposite way